# Добавление триггеров в Zabbix

Tags: php, symfony, zabbix

Столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно добавить механизм добавления триггеров в Zabbix. Сейчас реализовано обновление в классе `ZabbixBundle/Command/DataUpdateCommand.php`, но мне нужно реализовать добавление только триггеров. Раньше с подобными задачами не сталкивался, так что просто потерялся и даже не знаю что делать.

Comment: Имею ввиду - как вычлинить из данного скрипта (он общедоступен и идет в пакете заббикса) вытащить логику добавления только триггеров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз никто не в курсе, объясню сам :) 
Сбор ВСЕХ триггеров означает, что мы должны просто убрать фильтр из этого набора: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/ru/manual/api/reference/trigger/get

Т.е. будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
`$trigger_list = $zabbix->getTrigger([
    'output' => "extend",
    'selectAcknowledges' => "extend",
    'selectGroups' => "extend",
    'selectHosts' => "extend",
    'selectItems' => "extend",
    'selectDiscoveryRule' => "extend",
    'selectLastEvent' => "extend",
], "triggerid", "DESC");`
```

в массив $trigger_list приходит массив со всеми тиггерами. PS: не думайте, что description в этом массиве - имя триггера. Имя находится в ['items'][0]['name'].

дальше остается стандартное добавление (его можно скопировать прямо из ZabbixBundle/Command/DataUpdateCommand.php).